# How to update Realm value from dynamic fieldname

Tags: android, json, realm, pojo

As the title says, I want to update a value from an existing record dynamically based on the field name.

So I have json here that I've formatted it to POJO, based on certain condition I want to update thinktank_roundtable_b_cass_iags to Yes or asia_clean_energy_summit_conference to Yes or any other keys to Yes, how do I achieve this?

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "total: 1",
    "fields": [
        {
            "eventuid": "45c-3red-uuid-332",
            "thinktank_roundtable_b_cass_iags": "-",
            "asia_clean_energy_summit_conference": "-",
            "notwishtoreceivenews": "Yes",
            "status": "OK",
            ... (long list)
        }
    ]
}
```

converted to POJO

```
public class EventsModel extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private Integer id;
    private String eventuid;
    private String thinktank_roundtable_b_cass_iags;
    private String notwishtoreceivenews;
    private String asia_clean_energy_summit_conference;
    private String status;

    ... (long list)

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEventuid() {
        return eventuid;
    }

    public void setEventuid(String eventuid) {
        this.eventuid= eventuid;
    }

    public String getThinktank_roundtable_b_cass_iags() {
        return thinktank_roundtable_b_cass_iags;
    }

    public void setThinktank_roundtable_b_cass_iags(String thinktank_roundtable_b_cass_iags) {
        this.thinktank_roundtable_b_cass_iags = thinktank_roundtable_b_cass_iags;
    }

    public String getNotwishtoreceivenews() {
        return notwishtoreceivenews;
    }

    public void setNotwishtoreceivenews(String notwishtoreceivenews) {
        this.notwishtoreceivenews = notwishtoreceivenews;
    }

    public String getAsia_clean_energy_summit_conference() {
        return asia_clean_energy_summit_conference;
    }

    public void setAsia_clean_energy_summit_conference(String asia_clean_energy_summit_conference) {
        this.asia_clean_energy_summit_conference = asia_clean_energy_summit_conference;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    ...
}
```

And this part has made me confused for several days

```
public void updateEvent(final String fieldname, final String eventuid) {
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                EventsModel model = realm.where(EventsModel.class)
                        .equalTo("eventuid", eventuid)
                        .findFirst();

                // PART TO UPDATE
                // Failed this part 
                model.set[Field Name]("Yes");
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.e("Update Event", "Successfully Updated");
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this 
it will help you for update existing realm model

```
public void updateFeild(T tc, String feildName, String value) {
    try {
        Method[] methods = tc.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            String method_name = "realmSet$" + feildName;
            if (method_name.equals(method.getName())) {
                Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                realm.beginTransaction();
                method.invoke(tc, value);
                realm.commitTransaction();
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here above T is generic class which indicates any realm class object

Comment: I dont think you understand what I want to do...I want to set (eventModel.set[field name]("Yes") with the fieldname that I passed to the function updateEvent()

Comment: I have updated solution please check this. 
This is working for me :)

Comment: so in this case T is EventsModel realm class object?

Comment: yes it is object of generic class , it can be any realm class object.
if you want then you can use there EventsModel also as parameter

Comment: nothing happened...but I think its in the right track